# Invalid provisioning profile (iOS distribution certificate)

Tags: ios, certificate, profile, provisioning-profile

I've a iOS developer account, in the past couple years, I've been testing debuging my apps in iOS devices with a development certificate.

Now, I've created a distribution certificate, but after I generate a provisioning profile, it status became 'Invalid' and it doesn't show any additional info, the expiration date is: Oct 04, 2017

Any suggestion?

Comment: if the error is invalid issuer, try removing invalid certificate first

Comment: The certificate is valid, it appears to be ok keychain access